# Pandas - Understanding how rolling averages work

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

So I'm trying to calculate rolling averages, based on some column and some groupby columns.
In my case:

rolling column = RATINGS,

groupby_columns = ["DEMOGRAPHIC","ORIGINATOR","START_ROUND_60","WDAY","PLAYBACK_PERIOD"]

one group of my data looks like that:

[image: one group of the data]

my code to compute the rolling average is:

```
df['rolling']= df.groupby(groupby_columns_keys)['RATINGS'].\
apply(lambda x: x.shift().rolling(10,min_periods=1).mean())
```

What I don't understand is what is happening when the RATINGS value are starting to be NaN.

As my window size is 10, I would expect the second number in the test (index 11) to be:

```
np.mean([178,479,72,272,158,37,85.5,159,107,164.55]) = 171.205
```

But it is instead 171.9444, and same apply to the next numbers.
What is happening here?
And how I should calculate the next rolling averages the way I want (simply to average the 10 last ratings - and if ratings is NaN to take the calculated average of the previous row instead).

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> np.mean([178,479,72,272,158,37,85.5,159,107,**164.55**]) = 171.205

Where does the 164.55 come from? The rest of those values are from the "RATINGS" column and the 164.55 is from the "rolling" column. Maybe I am misunderstanding what the `rolling` function does.

Comment: 164.55 is the average of the 10 first ratings

Comment: I see, so if the value in "RATINGS" is NaN, it should then take the value from the "rolling" column? Then aren't you taking an average of averages?

Comment: Why an average of averages?

Comment: It seems to me that it will just average the last X valid data points where X < window size. So your window size is 10, but in the last 10 data points, there is 1 NaN, so only 9 valid data points.  So np.mean([178,479,72,272,158,37,85.5,159,107]) = 171.9444.  It is unclear to me why the last value in the window would default to the previously calculated rolling average.

Comment: Got you, and +1-ed for your help. But my question was exactly how I default it to the previously calculated rolling average.

Comment: Ah, I see. What would your expected behavior be if your entire window is NaN? For example, if there were 10 NaN in a row, would your rolling average just continue averaging the previous rolling averages continuously? In any case, I think you might need to write a custom function that looks at each value and determines if it needs to replace the NaN with a calculated value. It's a bit tricky to me since each subsequent NaN will be based on the previous rolling average, I can't think of a pandas function that would do this.